# Docker: resource issues inside containers

Tags: docker

I have a centos7.4 container running. Inside this container I am doing a variety of things. I am noticing very frequent issues such as

```
clang-5.0: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Resource temporarily unavailable.
```

And

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Cannot create GC thread. Out of system resources.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

And

```
make[1]: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And

```
fork() failed: Command could not be run:
```

If I execute the same "variety of things" on the same Docker host but outside of the container, i dont run into issues. I am trying to understand if this is docker specific thing that I am not aware of. Docker by default inherits host's resources correct? i.e. number of cores and mem

i see this then i run docker stats

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
8cbc44773def        my-rh6     1.98%               48.59MiB / 251.6GiB   0.02%               33.8GB / 31.6GB     65.9MB / 11.5MB     26
683313a4e70e        my-rh7     85.99%              73.26MiB / 251.6GiB   0.03%               21.1GB / 1.31GB     269MB / 26.6MB      6
```

my host has 72 cores and 250G mem. so mem seems to be the same. I have no idea how java would run out of mem with 250G being available...

When I do execute "variety of things" i do see CPU % go above 1000% at times which i am not sure if its the norm. If i run the same thing outside of container, sar doesnt show cpu consumption nowhere near 1000%. (70% max at times)

Comment: is this a linux host?

Comment: @avigil yes on centos 6.8 and 7.4 images